# That is I vs That is me

Tags: linking-verbs, subject-complement

I understand that after a linking verb, the noun should be in subject case. So why do we say "that is me" instead of "that is I" ? Is the former grammatically accurate?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your context. The “is I” [so-called] rule is one of many nineteenth-century creations of prescriptivists trying to make English fit the grammar of Latin (Why not force, say, Navajo to fit the grammar of, oh I dunno, Thai?).

But many people do expect the subject case, so although “It is me” has a centuries-old pedigree, in situations where you feel it important that your usage be judged as proper you may wish to go with *I*.

Comment: Who Killed Cock Robin?  just wouldn't work so well with 'me'… but it does hark back as far as 16thC. I agree, I think people should give up with this insistence these days.

Comment: I would add that even French—a language with a much greater excuse to be shoehorned into its ancestral (Latin) form—eschews the subject case: *C’est moi* is 100% correct French, and \**C’est je* is just weird.

Comment: So for those who follow traditional English grammar would say "that is I" and in modern English it is idiomatic to say "that is me".

Comment: Even traditional Grammars consider "that is I" to be "over-correct" (E.g. Wren and Martin: "126. Grammarians formerly recommended that the complement of the verb to be, when it
is expressed by a pronoun, should be in the nominative case. Today the use of the
nominative form is considered extremely formal and over-correct. We usually use the
objective form.")

Answer (score 1):

> *That is I/me.*

I'm assuming that the sentence is used as a stand alone one, perhaps where the speaker is pointing to some picture of himself/herself.

There is no rule of English requiring a nominative form where a pronoun is complement of the verb "be". Such a rule would fail to allow for a construction we all use most of the time: just about everyone says "That is me".

I don't say that "That is I" is ungrammatical, but it does represent an unusually formal style of speech.